# Handle 401 with ReasonPhrase

Tags: javascript, authentication, angularjs, cors

I have an AngularJS web app, where I am using Basic Authentication. This works well, but when users enter the wrong email or password, I want to give them a good error message. Therefore I return 401 with a reasonphrase like explained here: http://leastprivilege.com/2013/04/22/web-api-security-basic-authentication-with-thinktecture-identitymodel-authenticationhandler/

This works fine and the 401 with reasonphrases are returned correctly. However using Angular's $http interprets the response with status code 0 and not 401, furthermore there is no chance to read the reason, that I want to pass on to my users. Eg. unknown email or wrong password.

I've tested this in Chrome and Firefox and have been browsing through tons of questions without finding any answers. I've implemented a response interceptor like this:

```
$httpProvider.responseInterceptors.push(function ($timeout, $q) {
        return function (promise) {
            return promise.then(function (successResponse) {
                if (successResponse.config.method.toUpperCase() != 'GET')
                    showMessage('Success', 'successMessage', 5000);
                return successResponse;

            }, function (errorResponse) {
                console.log("status: " + errorResponse.status, errorResponse.config);
                switch (errorResponse.status) {
                    case 0:
                    case 401:
                        showMessage('Wrong email or password', 'errorMessage', 20000);
                        break;
                    case 403:
                        showMessage('You don\'t have the right to do this', 'errorMessage', 20000);
                        break;
                    case 500:
                        showMessage('Server internal error: ' + errorResponse.data, 'errorMessage', 20000);
                        break;
                    default:
                        showMessage('Error ' + errorResponse.status + ': ' + errorResponse.data, 'errorMessage', 20000);
                }
                return $q.reject(errorResponse);
            });
        };
    });
```

When debugging the interceptor works, but the status code is never 401, but 0 instead. In the Chrome console it shows:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost:64044/api/user/login/. Origin     
http://localhost:63546 is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.
```

Is there any chance I can get this to work?

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that you are making a request to a different server than the one which is hosting the JavaScripts. You will have to use jsonp to get around this error message.